# JavaScript - Drag and drop

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing a tic tac toe javascript drag and drop project and I am having troubles making it decide who won the game. If someone could push me in the right direction that would be great!(code is below)

What I want to do is when I drop one of the x's(in my case its a dragon) and o's(a rat) into one of the squares I have created I want it to detected that it is in there so I can create something like this

(first off drag1 = the id for the dragon image and drag2 is the img id for rat)

```
if(sq1 == drag1 && sq2 == drag1 && sq3 == drag1){
  alert("Dragon Wins!");
}
else if (sq4 == drag1 && sq5 == drag1 && sq6 == drag1){
  alert("Dragon Wins!");
}
```

etc....

So how would I get started so that the square detects what image is in it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually several ways to achieve this. A straightforward one would be to look at the src attribute of the image tag you're passing:

```
function drop(ev) {
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var yourImageTag = document.getElementById(data);

    if (yourImageTag.src.match(/dragon/)) {
        //handle case dragon here
    }
    else {
        //handle case for rat here
    }

    //your code for adding the image to the table row

}
```

While this should work there are some better solutions, which are a bit more robust in my opinion.

You could add an data attribute to your image tag and use jQuery to get it when you need to decide.

```
<img data-type="dragon" src="..."> //this would go in your html markup
var imageType = $(yourImageTag).data('type'); //this would go in your drop function
```

Another way would be to set the type with the dataTransfer object when you start dragging it.